# Java hashCode should relay on final variables

Tags: java, hashcode

```
public lass A {
    private String id;
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)    {
        if (!(obj instanceof A)) 
            return false;

        A a = (A) obj;

        return new EqualsBuilder()
                .append(id, a.id)
                .append(attr1, a.attr1
                .append(attr2, a.attr2)
                .isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder()
                .append(id)
                .hashCode();
    }
}
```

In the example class, **id should be final** for hashCode() to work properly.
Otherwise objet will just disapper from collection after property modification causing memory leaks.

```
A a = new A();
a.setId("id1");
a.setAttr1("attr1");
a.setAttr2("attr2");

Set set = new HashSet();
set.add(a);

set.contains(a) == true;

a.setId("id2");

set.contains(a) == false;
```

Am I missing anything? Why It is not stated in HashCodeBuilder javadoc?
This made me stuck because I've seen so many cases where hashCode and equals relay on the same set of fields. Nobody seem have in mind attributes modification...

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)    {
        if (!(obj instanceof A)) 
            return false;

        A a = (A) obj;

        return new EqualsBuilder()
                .append(id, a.id)
                .append(attr1, a.attr1
                .append(attr2, a.attr2)
                .isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder()
                .append(id)
                .append(attr1)
                .append(attr2)
                .hashCode();
    }
```

Comment: This is true regardless of whether you use the `HashCodeBuilder` convenience class or not.  Anyway, this is a constraint on what you put in a `HashMap`, not on the `hashCode` itself.

Comment: Doesn't Hibernate require setters on all mapped fields to work properly?  It would be unusable if all the fields used in `hashCode` had to be `final`.

Comment: It should be documented in bold for developers to remember not to use attributes that are subject to normal modification in hashCode(). If it is not possible to do in Hibernate entities, it should be done where possible in all other places, isn't it?

Comment: `hashCode` and `equals` must use the same fields. Ideally they should all be final.

Comment: hashCode must use subset of the fields used in equals, not all of them isn't it? Idealy they should be final, anyway client code must not modify them after putting in collection and except them to behave properly in that collction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's documented in the [Object.hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) javaDocs:

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>   execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>   return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>   comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>   consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>   of the same application.

The fields used being final would satisfy this. If it's not possible then you can still use them in `hashCode` as long as you don't change their values later.